# Can I upgrade existing T12 fluorescent fixtures to T8 just by replacing the ballast and bulbs?

Tags: lighting

I was going to replace the fluorescent T12 fixtures around my house with T8 fixtures, but I noticed that the T8 bulbs seem to fit just fine into the T12 fixtures.  It seems like I could save myself a few bucks and maybe some hassle if I just replace the ballasts instead of replacing the entire fixtures.  Plus, I could make sure to buy higher-efficiency or higher-quality ballasts instead of just using whatever mystery ballasts come with the fluorescent fixtures at the home improvement store.  Is there anything wrong with this plan?

Comment: Disagree that T8 ballasts are a better ballast. Where I work, we're replacing T8 ballasts every 1 to 5 years. The old T12 ballasts that are coming out have been there for at least 10 years, and some as long as 25-30 years, and those were still working when removed. Yes, T8 ballasts are lighter weight, and may be more efficient, but do not last as long as the old T12 ones.

Comment: Have you considered using LED bulbs instead? Most designs for straight tube fluorescent replacements just bypass the ballast -- taking it out of the circuit completely. They should save more energy than the T8. The downside is the risk of how well developed the long tube LED lights are. I have heard mixed comments about their reliability and some of those have focused on where made and by whom - essentially issues of quality of construction.

Comment: @JKEngineer that's a good alternative now that LEDs have dropped so much in price over the past couple years. When I originally posted this question, LEDs were still very pricey but late 2015/early 2016 I saw that a local warehouse store started stocking 4' LED shop lights for around $30, but maybe they have the same reliability issues.

Comment: EarthLED has 4ft 2200 lumen 4000k LED tubes that work in t8/t12 fixtures for $9.99.  I just finished removing the ballasts from 8 shop lights in my garage and installing 16 bulbs. A HUGE increase in light and much better color rendering.  If they last as long as advertised I'll never have to replace them (they'll outlast me :-).  And no more Mercury from the occasional broken tube (these are plastic and of course contain no Mercury). Rewiring one fixture takes about 5 minutes after you've done one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace ballast and lamps, and for extra savings, on a four tube per bay fixture, get a 3-lamp ballast and run only three tubes.

The extra efficiency of the smaller tube plus high-frequency electronic ballast means that three T-8 tubes can put out nearly the same light as four T-12 tubes.

The ballast tends to be a lot smaller, and weigh much less than the t-12 ballasts.

[image]

**Wiring varies -- your ballast will have a wiring diagram**.  But to give you an idea, here is an example of wiring for an *instant-start* electronic ballast (which are easier to wire, but tend to fail bulbs faster); and a *rapid-start* or *programmed-start* electronic ballast (which often matches the old magnetic ballasts):

[image]

For the smaller 18AWG solid-core wires in ballasts, don't use the common yellow/red wire nuts.  Use *blue* wire-nuts, or for instance, push-in wiring connectors such as Gardner Bender PushGard, others are available... make sure the size is correct for 18 AWG wire.

[image]
[image]

You can reduce number of bulbs, since T8s are brighter.  A complete building rewire from four T12 to three T8 tubes per fixture eliminated 38 tubes and at 32W each, was a savings of 1216 Watts in power reduction if you only count tube elimination and not also ballast efficiency over mangetic (est. 10-15w per ballast replaced). PLUS, NO FLICKER! For someone with fast vision, not seeing 60Hz flicker in the peripheral vision was almost worth more than the power savings.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on the wire connectors and 3-tube ballasts.  I only have seven 2-tube fixtures to upgrade in my house, but after I've gotten some practice at home I might upgrade the dozen or so 4-tube fixtures at my wife's shop, which run about 14 hrs/day, 6 days a week.

Comment: Heh, the two tube fixtures are easy, follow the wiring diagram on the ballast. I had some two-tube hanging shop lights with a good fixture but a really cheap ballast (why they were so inexpensive). They used the standard ballast mounting, so it was easy to convert them from $25 to $50 fixtures by spending $14.50 plus tubes. No more flickering, weird starts, dead ballasts and old, inefficient tubes.

Comment: For extra savings dump the ballast and put in retro fit led direct wire lamps. I purchased some 22w 4' direct wire lamps for 6 or 7 ea. These lamps should last over 50000 hours with a higher output than t8. If you just factor the lamps and ballast these are less expensive . now add the energy savings and longer life and they are way cheaper want to save even more drop to 18 w led's and have the same light level for even less.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, this is done all the time.

Just change the ballast and lamps.

Pay close attention to the wiring diagram on the ballast as the new electronic T8 ballast are wired quite differently from the old magnetic T12 ballasts.

Comment: You may find you don't save much money; often a replacement ballast is as much as a new fixture - but, as you note, you can at least pick your ballast, and part of the reason the ballast can cost as much or more than a replacement fixture will be that it's potentially a better ballast. You also have to shop like heck or you can get _really_ overcharged on them; and sometimes you'll find that the maker has a ballast you'd like more but nobody seems to stock (or even be willing to order in.) Had a 4 bulb I gave up and got a low output ballast since the high-output version was unobtanium.

Comment: At $16 ballast cost per fixture, ballast costs weren't enough of a concern if we're talking about quality, built-in fixtures. If you're talking about those ultra-cheap hang from the ceiling things, maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about the wiring and notes about cost.  I found some ballasts in the $16 price range at Lowe's and Amazon.  The existing fixtures are just shop lights, but even the new shop lights I bought for my garage were $30-$35 (I shied away from the $10 Wal-Mart special).  So I guess I'll still save a good chunk of money by upgrading the existing fixtures with higher-quality ballasts.

Comment: Cheap ballast do not last, combined with cheap lamps you might get 2-3 years and you will be putting in new ballast, been there and done that with close to 100 to save my company $ as the superintendent was sold a bill of goods in my opinion now all lighting is purchased through the electrical department.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the fixture type, since I'm working on a drop ceiling with drop in troffers, I'm inclined to prefer a new LED troffer with integrated LED strips.

One they go, in a decade or two, just replace the whole troffer again. 
Ballasts are a p.i.t.a.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the ballast- as most t8 tubes have an electronic one inside.  If you put them in t12- you will burn the bulb up and they will work sporadically before they die.  Also the fixture gets blackend.  You must use non shunted lamp holders.  you cant just "change the light".

You put 115 volts to ONE END only- and use the black and white wire- both to each lamp holder- but look for wiring diagram and get the right lampholders before you go rewiring things.

instructions here: http://forestlighting.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/ForestLighting_InstructionManual.pdf

Comment: Some LED tubes are double-ended, hot wire to one end an neutral to the other. So make sure the lamp you get matches the way you rewire the fixture.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like parts suppliers are pushing lies hard. I've seen people put T8 tubes in a T12 fixture multiple times with no issues what-so-ever. The bulbs work reliably, but are brighter.

Comment: maybe for certain ballasts where you got lucky, but even then I doubt the service life of the T8 will be very long. You are overdriving it well beyond spec. The electrical characteristics are quite different, and a different ballast is warranted for peak performance. Part of what T8 ballasts do is save money, e.g. in my direct measurement 95VA for a T12 ballast and 62VA for a T8. 33 watts less.  At .12/kwh, 1 watt continuous = $1/year, so it pays for itself in 7 months of burntime (e.g. 2 yrs at 9x5).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It would be good if you could address @Harper's concerns on this.  And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score -7):

yes you can change from T12 to T8, Just change the light, and you are done.

Comment: You must change the ballast & bulb together.  Changing to a T8 light bulb alone will not work.

Comment: @Ben T8 lamps will work on a T12 ballast but you will greatly diminish the life span of the lamp. For a quick fix it will work but, if you have the materials to do it right, just do it right.